# Is it possible to use bundle from a different package when calling localizedUserNotificationString

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, swift-package-manager

My app had its localization resources (**.lproj* files) in the Main bundle. So I was able to use `localizedUserNotificationString` as expected.

I have since modularized the app and the resources have now moved to a new SPM package for shared resources. After this change `localizedUserNotificationString` has stopped formatting strings from arguments.

I had to replace

```
NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: title, arguments: args)
```

with

```
String(format: String.localizationHelper(title), arguments: titleArgs ?? [])
```

Where the `localizationHelper` is defined in the resources package to use the correct bundle.

```
func localizationHelper(key: String) {
    return NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: nil, bundle: .module, value: "", comment: "")
}
```